# Kattis - Recount C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to solve https://open.kattis.com/problems/recount in C#. I have my code written but I know I'm missing something but I'm stuck and I've been working on this for a few days. Whenever I try to run my code I receive a runtime error and I know it's because I need to be able to add a user inputted list to convert to a dictionary but I'm not sure how.

Running on .NET 3.1 for school

Here is the code I have currently

```
namespace Kattis_Solution___Recount
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SortedDictionary<string, int> votes = new SortedDictionary<string, int>();
            List<string> names = new List<string>();
            string name = "";

            name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write(name);
            Console.Write("\n");
            int max = 0;
            string winner = "";
            while (name[0] != '*')
            {
                if (votes[name] == 0)
                {
                    names.Add(name);
                }
                votes[name]++;
                if (votes[name] > max)
                {
                    max = votes[name];
                    winner = name;
                }
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write(name);
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
            Console.Write(winner);
            Console.Write("\n");

            for (int i = 1; i < names.Count; i++)
            {
                if (votes[names[i]] == max && winner != names[i])
                {
                    Console.Write("Runoff!");
                    Console.Write("\n");
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We should not have to go somewhere else and watch a video or read something to understand your problem and what your code is supposed to do.  Please visit the [help] and study [ask] to learn how the site works

Comment: You are also leaving out other essential details such as **which** runtime error and **where** it occurs. Please **[edit]** the question and include those details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this if the entry isnt there

```
            if (votes[name] == 0) {
                names.Add(name);
            }
```

(unlike some other languages - c++ for example)

You need to do

```
            if (!votes.ContainsKey(name))  {
                names.Add(name);
                votes[name] = 0;
            }
```

See docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.item?view=net-6.0

> The value associated with the specified key. If the specified key is not found, a get operation throws a KeyNotFoundException, and a set operation creates a new element with the specified key.

Comment: Thank you for the help, and I apologize for the lack of clarification, this is my first question.

Comment: @MauiB. please tick the answer as correct if it fixed the issue for you